# How can I generate a random speed for my racers in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, random

I am trying to create a basic racer that pits two sprites against each other. After a bit of tweaking, I have made my racers move 550 px to the right at a slow speed

There are my racers and the button that allows them to race

```
<center><button id="race">Race!!</button></center>
<div class="kimo"><img id="kimo" src="images/kimo.gif"  alt="Kimo" height="80"></div>
<div class="kahuna"><img id="kahuna" src="images/kahuna.gif"  alt="Kahuna" height="80"></div>
```

Here is the script that animates them

```
<script>
$("#race").click(function(){
$(".kimo").animate({"left": "+=550px"}, "slow");
$(".kahuna").animate({"left": "+=550px"}, "slow");
});
</script>
```

Now here is where The speed is obviously 'slow', but I would like to have them generate a random speed whenever the button is clicked, as well as using the animation only once. As in, the racers move 550px TOTAL.

Other things I need to accomplish: Whoever reaches the end of the 550px first, text will appear declaring either Kimo or Kahuna the winner.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.random` to generate a speed, but you will first have to figure out the maximum and minimum speed - the minimum speed is exceptionally important because there is a chance that Math.random will generate a number so small that the animation will take arbitrarily long to complete.

[Edit]: OP asked if it is possible to trigger the animation only once - I have added the `.unbind()` method, as well as assigned a handler to the function.

```
<script>
// Assign handler name, so that we can unbind it specifically
$("#race").click(function animateSprite(){
    // Unbind after first click
    $(this).unbind('click', animateSprite);

    // Set minimum speed
    var minSpeed = 1000;

    // Get random speed
    var kimoSpeed = parseInt(minSpeed + Math.random()*1000, 10),
        kahunaSpeed = parseInt(minSpeed + Math.random()*1000, 10);

    // In this case, the lowest possible speed is 1000, 
    // and the highest possible speed is 2000.
    // You are of course free to adjust the speed.

    // Animate
    $(".kimo").animate({"left": "+=550px"}, kimoSpeed);
    $(".kahuna").animate({"left": "+=550px"}, kahunaSpeed);

    // And if you want to decide who is the fastest, and assuming that you have an element with the id of "announce"
    // Delay announcement by 500ms after the slowest racer
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(kimoSpeed < kahunaSpeed) {
            // Declare Kimo as winner, e.g.
            // $("#announce").text("Kimo has won the race!");
        } else {
            // Declare Kahuna as winner
            // $("#announce").text("Kahuna has won the race!");
        }
    }, Math.max.apply(Math, [kimoSpeed, kahunaSpeed])+500);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is an incredibly helpful answer :)

Comment: I tried to implement it into my code and they still move the same speed.

Nonetheless, you have given me really great information and insight and I will keep trying until it works

Comment: Actually, it was a simple error on my part. It worked like a charm. Now I just have to make sure the button only works once. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want the button to work only once, you can use `$(this).unbind('click');` within the `click` function.

Comment: Thank you Terry! Do you know if there is any way to delay the announcement until after the race?

Comment: Use the `setTimeout()` function, e.g. `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1000)`. 

Please accept the answer if it has helped you.